# Is a Transit visa required by a US citizen with an overnight Narita, Japan layover?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, transit-visas, nrt

I'm a US passport holder. My flight lands at Narita airport at 4 pm and does not fly out till 11 am next day.

Do I need a transit visa?

Is it okay for me to leave the airport to explore and come back next morning?

Answer (score 10):

US citizen are entitled to stay up to 90 days as a tourist in Japan. Answer is from official [Embassy Of Japan USA](http://www.us.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/travel_and_visa.html).

- **A visa is NOT necessary for US passport holders visiting Japan for a short-term stay of less than 90 days with the purpose of tourism and business**.

Since you have a 19  hours layover at Narita airport, you can simply enjoy visa free acess to Narita city. Further you also don't need any transit visa as a US citizen.

Comment: Not just Narita City, technically all of Japan (well as much as you can fit into your layover).